# Unexpected behavior when updating a numpy array using a Python list

Tags: python, numpy

```
t=0
abig= zeros((10000,150))    
aa=[0 for i in range(150)]
print abig[0]

while 1:
    aa=abig[t]

    for k in range(150):

        for i in range(150):         
            ppp=aa[k]+nk[k]*(1-iris[k][3]*aa[i]*iris[i][3]*kk[i][k])
        aa[k]=ppp

        if aa[k]<0:
            aa[k]=0
        if aa[k]>10:
            aa[k]=10
    print abig[0]
    abig[t+1]=aa
    t=t+1
    sds=subtract(abig[t-1],abig[t])
    if norm(sds)<0.0001:
        break
print t 
print aa
```

my expectation is assign each `abig[t]` to aa then do some calculation with aa then assign aa back to `abig[t+1]` then get the subtraction of those two.

But here is my result:

> "D:\Python27\python.exe"  "C:\Users\zlxstc\Desktop\database mining\assignment 3\Untitled 3.py" 
>   [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
>     0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
>     0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
>     0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
>     0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
>     0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
>     0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
>     0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
>     0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
>
> [ 0.02182929  0.01688619  0.01852881  0.02994012  0.02334267  0.02912904
>     0.01877934  0.02329373  0.01769912  0.01881822  0.02398082  0.02355713
>     0.02299379  0.02074258  0.02807412  0.02593361  0.02593361  0.02362391
>     0.02639219  0.01560549  0.02182929  0.01877934  0.0185701   0.02597403
>     0.03099814  0.02547771  0.02663825  0.03051572  0.01591343  0.01709986
>     0.02156567  0.02685285  0.0245459   0.02358491  0.02918856  0.02524615
>     0.02329373  0.02355713  0.02128565  0.02085941  0.02360718  0.02074258
>     0.0174703   0.01569859  0.02460025  0.0293772   0.01628399  0.02424242
>     0.02284148  0.02043736  0.02331002  0.02427184  0.03293808  0.01901864
>     0.02340824  0.01877934  0.01688619  0.01422677  0.02125399  0.02394063
>     0.02175332  0.0199005   0.02547771  0.02570694  0.02360718  0.0249004
>     0.02299908  0.02807412  0.02768549  0.02463054  0.01268231  0.01469508
>     0.02125399  0.02247191  0.02880184  0.02912904  0.03359086  0.02071251
>     0.0293772   0.02154708  0.01923077  0.03096934  0.01879699  0.01996008
>     0.01789229  0.03225806  0.02125399  0.01730703  0.02156567  0.0204165
>     0.0273224   0.03164557  0.01879699  0.02208481  0.02334267  0.01547988
>     0.03147624  0.0163292   0.02630887  0.01901864  0.01783167  0.02099958
>     0.01835199  0.01730703  0.01769912  0.0273224   0.02856327  0.01670844
>     0.03631082  0.0339098   0.02752546  0.02502503  0.01946661  0.02421894
>     0.02329373  0.0200441   0.01454334  0.02018978  0.01902226  0.02085941
>     0.02329373  0.02777778  0.01769912  0.02207993  0.02483855  0.02886003
>     0.02362391  0.02355713  0.01832845  0.01968504  0.02181025  0.01968504
>     0.0144655   0.01936483  0.02807412  0.02229654  0.02483855  0.02017756
>     0.01877934  0.02630887  0.01497006  0.01688619  0.02047083  0.01919754
>     0.0212766   0.02340824  0.02563445  0.01789229  0.01320481  0.02527167]
>   ...............
>   ...............

the two `abig[0]` are not the same. so the subtraction is `0`. Why?
there are some definition of `kk[]` and `nk[]` and `iris[]` above. Are they relevant?

Comment: Those are some of the worst variable names I've ever seen.

Comment: This would even impress the [cat confusers](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B2Je1CEPkUM)!

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems in your code (aside of the variable names choice). First, doing:

```
aa=abig[t]
```

doesn't make a copy of `abig[t]`. Instead `aa` and `abig[t]` refers to the same data so if you do something like:

```
aa[1] = 20
```

then automatically

```
abig[t][1] = 20
```

On the other hand, the order of the assignment is probably wrong. I suppose that what you want is:

```
abig[t] = aa
```

As `abig` seems to be a `numpy` array the `copy` method is implicitely used so the `abig[t]` is a copy of `aa` (they don't share the data).

Now doing:

```
abig[t][1] = 20
```

doesn't change `aa[1]`.

Second, this part of your code:

```
for i in range(150):         
    ppp=aa[k]+nk[k]*(1-iris[k][3]*aa[i]*iris[i][3]*kk[i][k])
aa[k]=ppp
```

is just the same than:

```
aa[k]=aa[k]+nk[k]*(1-iris[k][3]*aa[149]*iris[149][3]*kk[149][k])
```

so the loop is useless. I suppose what you really mean is

```
for i in range(150):         
    aa[k]=aa[k]+nk[k]*(1-iris[k][3]*aa[i]*iris[i][3]*kk[i][k])
```

(but not completly sure).

In summary, in your current implementation `aa`, `abig[t]` and `abig[t+1]` all refer to the same data so when you substract consecutive rows you got a bunch of zeroes.

Comment: +1 for heroic interpretation of ridiculous code

Comment: Just a smal thing, as he is using numpy appearently, the `abig[t+1] = aa` is actually OK. The first `aa = ...` being not a copy is the point though, depending on what its supposed to do, adding `.copy()` there should solve it, though it leaves a lot of vectorization and cleanup I guess.

Comment: @seberg Thanks for your comment. I've updated my answer accordingly.